# Не работает setInterval js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть html страница, которая использует `js` для отправки GET запроса к контроллеру:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles-ajax.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<script>
    var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/restShowAttempt');
    myRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (myRequest.readyState === 4) {
            document.getElementById('ajax-content').innerHTML = myRequest.responseText;
        }
    };

    function sendTheAJAX() {
        myRequest.send();
    }

    setInterval(sendTheAJAX, 2000);

</script>
<body>
<div id="ajax-content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`setInterval(sendTheAJAX, 2000);` срабатывает один раз.

Как правильно его использовать?

PS - изучаю `java` но на проекте требуется реализовать перезагрузку страницы со стороны клиента (с браузера). Буду благодарен, если учтете в ответах мою, отличную от `js` специализацию.

Спасибо

Comment: SrtInterval и document.reload()

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, спасибо конечно...но для меня ето все-равно, что `@ConditionalOnMissingFilterBean  и stream.map()` для Вас, если конечно не занимались `java` разработкой

Comment: Ни разу не занимался, но тем не менее обе вещи понял секунд за 30... может вопрос стоит в том что оно вам не надо? если даже лень глянуть описание обоих комманд... первая - установит интервал(условия прописать надеюсь на JS сможете? не сильно вроде синтаксис от явы отличается), вторая - перезагрузит страницу.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Спасибо за ответ. Но давайте не будем меряться ЧСВ. Если двумя командами можно решить данную задачу за 30 сек...то странно, что никому не нужно 25 баллов к рейтингу за 30 сек.. На js никогда не писал, только копипастил

Comment: "срабатывает один раз." - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @Igor, у меня контроллер при изменении данных в таблице меняет джсон, который передается на страницу. Плюс - поставил чекпоинт в классе контроллера. При переходе на страницу, как полагается, через 2 сек выводится корректные данные, но больше страница в контроллер не заглядывает и строка не меняется.

Comment: нет элемента с id `reveal`, поэтому падает на `document.getElementById('reveal').style.display` - проверь ошибки в консоли браузера.

Comment: @Grundy Видимо мусор..удалил ету троку - без изменений. Когда вручную перезагружаю - строка меняется

Comment: перенеси все что связано с myRequest  внутрь sendTheAJAX

Comment: @Grundy, большое спасибо большое. Последний совет решил проблему. Если напишете в ответах - 25 балов с меня..

Comment: Дело не в 25 балах..., а в том что у меня например есть желание помоч человеку разобраться как можно решить задачу а не написать за вас и для вас код который я и так в состоянии написать если вдруг он мне понадобится. Обратите внимание, как только вы приложили усилия помимо копипасты - вам помогли.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков да я понимаю все..и правильно делаете. Просто сейчас ну никак нет времени разбираться - да и видите на каких детских вещах сыплюсь.. Но зато на пол процента в js продвинулся)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В текущем коде Chrome показывает в консоли ошибку

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.

Что говорит о том, что перед вызовом `send` необходим вызов `open`.

Из-за этого стоит изменить код. Проще всего на каждый запрос создавать новый объект XMLHttpRequest:

```
function sendTheAJAX() {
    var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/restShowAttempt');
    myRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (myRequest.readyState === 4) {
            document.getElementById('ajax-content').innerHTML = myRequest.responseText;
        }
    };
    myRequest.send();
}

setInterval(sendTheAJAX, 2000);
```